# Execute function after time interval in searchbar - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want to **execute a function if user remains idle for 3 seconds after entering text in searchbar**.
I have tried using below code :

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {    
  ...    
    if ([searchText length] >= 3) { // If text length is greater than 3

      [NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
               selector:@selector(searchBarSearchButtonClicked:) object:searchBar];

      [self performSelector:@selector(searchBarSearchButtonClicked:)
                               withObject:searchBar afterDelay:3.0]; 

   }

}
```

The problem with this code is if **user enters text greater than 3 and presses enter then code execute twice** and  sometimes it **crashes due to "invalidate timer"**.

What changes should be done in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution by using `NSTimer`. Below is snippet :

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;    
    ...

    if ([searchText length] >= 3) { 

       timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0 target: self
             selector: @selector(SearchBarProxyCall) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];   
    }
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    ...
}

-(void)SearchBarProxyCall { 
    [self searchBarSearchButtonClicked:searchbar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks OK, you're missing something in `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` method,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
               selector:@selector(searchBarSearchButtonClicked:) object:searchBar];
    ....
}
```

Case 1: You've stop typing and it matched to exact 3 length, a timer will call above method and it'll execute exactly after 3 seconds.

Case 2: Timer is set for 3 seconds (if Case 1 is true), mean while you tap Search button (enter), it will call above delegate and cancel any previous call made to this method.

So it'll not call twice. Simple! :)

Comment: I have implemented searchBarSearchButtonClicked: of searchBar delegate. I have tried using cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: of NSRunLoop but didn't worked.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, I've tested this at my side and then given you the answer. Can you please tell me what happened with this logic?